# Extract dates from a string

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string like below in angular:-

```
 title : string = "Import csv for User test (6 Jul 2022 - 5 Oct 2022)
```

I want to extract dates in bracket and store it in two variables(start and end date)... Dates should also be in dd/mm/yyyy format... Any idea?

Comment: Your dates are not in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format you mentioned.

Comment: I need it in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DatePipe` to achieve this:

```
const dates = title.match(/(\d{1,2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4})/g);
```

Once you have the two dates, you can pass them to the pipe:

```
const startDate = this.datePipe.transform(dates[0], 'dd/MM/yyyy');
const endDate = this.datePipe.transform(dates[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Be sure to correctly initialize the `DatePipe`.

For example, the *italian* locale has the date formatted as you asked. So the init would looks like this:

`this.datePipe = new DatePipe('it-IT');`

#### If you don't want to use the date pipe

You can simply parse the date using JS native `Date` object:

You can declare a function like that:

```
private _formatDate(date: Date): string {
    const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const year = date.getFullYear().toString();
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}
```

and then you can modify the code I provided above like this:

```
const dates = title.match(/(\d{1,2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4})/g);
const startDate = this._formatDate(dates[0]);
const endDate = this._formatDate(dates[1]);
```

The result is the same, it's up to you what approach you want to follow.

Of course, all this logic is based on the condition that your initial string will always have the date inside the two parenthesis, spaced as you wrote. *If* the initial string isn't always formatted like you posted, you need to change the `regex`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
  title: string = 'Import csv for User test (6 Jul 2022 - 5 Oct 2022)';
  startDate: string = '';
  endDate: string = '';

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.extractDates();
  }

  extractDates() {
    const regex = /\((\d{1,2}\s\w+\s\d{4})\s-\s(\d{1,2}\s\w+\s\d{4})\)/;
    const matches = this.title.match(regex);
    if (matches && matches.length >= 3) {
      this.startDate = this.formatDate(matches[1]);
      this.endDate = this.formatDate(matches[2]);
    }
  }

  formatDate(dateString: string): string {
    const parts = dateString.split(' ');
    const formattedDate = new Date(`${parts[1]} ${parts[0]}, ${parts[2]}`);
    return this.datePipe.transform(formattedDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  }
```

make sure to add the `DatePipe` in providers array of the respective `module` or `standalone component`.